# How to format Microsoft Windows 10 USB stick?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, format

I have Microsoft Windows 10 Home installation USB stick. It's the small metal grey and blue flash drive that Microsoft provides. I want to format it, as appears to be corrupted. I tried but it contains read only attribute. I tried diskpart utility but it doesn't come out of read-only mode.

Comment: Did you use the clean command in diskpart?

Comment: The Windows 10 retail usb sticks have a different firmware that prevents the from being written or erased. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-retail-usb-remove-write-protection/bf35df8c-1cd4-4dbd-824f-2c5ddf924948